# Is it necessary to use all the columns defined as the primary key to query a Cassandra database?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, data-modeling

I am using Cassandra database and need to define the Primary Key which is a combination of partition key and clustering keys. The cassandra database needs to be queried based on the combination of two fields i.e. a **customer number** and **createdAt** (Unix timestamp value), as per the business requirement. These columns cannot be used as Primary key because they cannot uniquely identify a row in the database. So, is it correct to add the **uuid** column from database as a clustering key to make the primary key unique, so that the Primary key will become a combination of - **customerNumber**(Partition key), **createdAt** (ClusteringKey), **uuid**( clustering key). However the database will never be queried based on the whole primary key. It will always be queried based on the part of the Primary key i.e. **Customer** **Number** and **createdAt**. **uuid** will never be used to query the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, your PRIMARY KEY definition looks like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (customerNumber,createdAt,uuid)
```

> It will always be queried based on the part of the Primary key

Yes, querying by *part* of the PRIMARY KEY definition is fine, in your case.  Cassandra tries to restrict queries to a single node, and it achieves this by ensuring that an entire partition is written to a single node (and then replicated).  Because of this, you really only need to supply the *partition key* on your queries (`customerNumber`), and they should work.

Supplying an additional PRIMARY KEY component however, is helpful.  In a high-throughput scenario, the smaller you can keep your result set payloads, the better.

**tl;dr;**

Querying by `customerNumber` and `createdAt` will be just fine.